# quantum state extraction

Tags: quantum-computing

Here's a simple circuit with an input state applied:

```
    qt = QuantumCircuitOperator[QuantumOperator["CNOT"]];
    qt[QuantumState["10"]]["Formula"]
```

which gives the output |11> or in InputForm:

```
    QuditName[{1, 1}, "Dual" -> False]
```

My question is: how can I extract the values 11 from |11>?

Comment: Try: `QuditName[{1, 1}, "Dual" -> False][[1]] // FromDigits`

Comment: Yes, that works, many thanks!